# I'm receiving "Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute." during foreach

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework-4.1

I need confirmation of my approach for this, I'm using EF and ASP.NET MVC and I'm trying to remove entities based on user selection (i.e based on what they have checked/unchecked).

To do this I'm looking at the Ids that are passed from the form from the checkboxes, matching what I have in the database and then first adding any which are new and then removing any which don't match.

Following is the code that I originally had:

```
        [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Edit(int id, FormCollection collection, VMinstanceRole vmodel)
    {
        try
        {
            var instancerole = db.instanceRoles.Find(id);

            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                UpdateModel<instanceRole>(instancerole, "instanceRole");
                var keys = instancerole.rights.Select( c => c.Id);

                foreach (var pid in vmodel.selectedId.Except(keys))
                {
                    var right = new right { Id = pid };
                    db.rights.Attach(right);
                    instancerole.rights.Add(right);
                }

                foreach (var pid in keys.Except(vmodel.selectedId))
                {
                    var right = instancerole.rights.Where(c => c.Id == pid).Single();
                    instancerole.rights.Remove(right);
                }


                db.SaveChanges();
            }

            // TODO: Add update logic here

            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        catch (InvalidCastException e) 
        {
            return View();
        }
    }
```

However, the following error was presented "Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute."

So to try and resolve this I decided to keep a seperate list and remove it based on teh list afterwards to overcome the error:

```
        [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Edit(int id, FormCollection collection, VMinstanceRole vmodel)
    {
        try
        {
            var instancerole = db.instanceRoles.Find(id);
            List<right> removeList = new List<right>();
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                UpdateModel<instanceRole>(instancerole, "instanceRole");
                var keys = instancerole.rights.Select( c => c.Id);

                foreach (var pid in vmodel.selectedId.Except(keys))
                {
                    var right = new right { Id = pid };
                    db.rights.Attach(right);
                    instancerole.rights.Add(right);
                }

                foreach (var pid in keys.Except(vmodel.selectedId))
                {
                    var right = instancerole.rights.Where(c => c.Id == pid).Single();
                    removeList.Add(right);
                }

                foreach (var right in removeList)
                {
                    instancerole.rights.Remove(right);
                }
                db.SaveChanges();
            }

            // TODO: Add update logic here

            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        catch (InvalidCastException e) 
        {
            return View();
        }
    }
```

This seems to work, however, I'm not sure whether I've done the right thing. Mainly becuase I'm doing another loop. Is there a better way to approach this or is this good enough ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
foreach (var pid in keys.Except(vmodel.selectedId).ToList())
{
    var right = instancerole.rights.Where(c => c.Id == pid).Single();
    instancerole.rights.Remove(right);
}
```

Enumerator you enumerate in foreach loop will be already disposed by the moment you delete your first item.

Comment: Hi Ilya, thanks for replying I see what you mean. This feels alot more better than what I have. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

You found one standard solution. The other solution that works would be to call ToList on the LINQ operation that produces your keys object: doing so would *disconnect* keys from instanceroles collection, allowing for arbitrary independent modifications on the original collection.

Comment: hi dasblinkenlight, thaks for replying I was a little confused whether I should store the ToList in another variable or not, but I think i've got it now. thanks for pointing me the direction.

Answer (score 0):

The reason for not being able to edit a collection when enumerating with `foreach` is well enough documented here alone (just check the 'related' links to the side), and in knowing you can't do that, you could use a simple `for` loop and amend to index upon removal of an item - this allows you to maintain one loop.

```
for (int i = 0; i < max; i++) {
  //if removing an item 
  //manipulate the index as desired...
  i--;
}
```